# Removing Redundant X-axis labels from group of boxplots

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I have a dataframe with over 100 samples and 13 different features (12 numeric, one binary categorical [called 'Compare_this_one' below]). I am trying to quickly pull out a series of subplots comparing all of the features' statistics across the binary categories. The below code does most of what I want.  I am just struggling with the aesthetic editing.

1. How do I remove the redundant x-axis labels (or all of them)?
2. How can I increase the title size in each subplot?  I already adjusted all of the fontsizes with rcParam (which worked fine for all my other plots), but it doesn't seem to have impacted this plot.
3. How do I increase the padding between each plot? A couple of my y-axes have larger values, and they overlap with plots to the left.

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 12), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKL'))
df['Compare_this_one'] = np.random.choice(range(1, 3), df.shape[0])
fig, ax_test = plt.subplots(4,3, sharex=True)
bp = df.boxplot(by='Compare_this_one',ax=ax_test,layout=(4,3))
plt.show()
```

[image: Boxplots that need some adjustments]

Thanks, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bp` var is a list of the axes of the subplots. You can set the label of each of these to your liking:

```
[ax.set_xlabel('') for ax in bp]
```

Comment: Thanks!  Any idea how to increase the title sizes?

Comment: [ax.set_title(ax.get_title(), fontdict=dict(fontsize=16)) for ax in bp]